# How do you make the floating label text black for material-ui V1

Tags: material-ui

Simply need to use `withStyles` some how to edit the default color from the primary/error color to simply just use black. But since the update from 0.19.0 to beta 1 this doesn't seem possible now.

Answer (score 0):

The error message (the one **under** the text input) is using the object under `theme.palette.error` ([see source](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/e5a81a89efcb5054e5b9eda9f06381b3526614d0/src/Form/FormHelperText.js#L24)) to choose which color to use.

That same palette color is used [for the text field label](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/e5a81a89efcb5054e5b9eda9f06381b3526614d0/src/Form/FormLabel.js#L21) too.

If you want to change both at the same time the right approach would be to use a custom theme that rewrites the `theme.palette.error` to something else.

```
import { createMuiTheme, createPalette } from 'material-ui/styles';
import grey from 'material-ui/colors/grey';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: createPalette({
    error: grey
  })
});
```

If you want to change just the FormHelperText color then you could customize it in theme [by using the `overrides` parameter](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/customization/themes/#customizing-all-instances-of-a-component-type).

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiFormHelperText: {
      error: {
        color: 'black'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Is there an example of making a custom theme like they used to have back in < 0.19.0 versions?

Comment: The links in the answer are references to the documention about custom themes. It‘s pretty easy, actually.

Answer (score 0):

To change the Label of the TextField in the current version (v1.2.1)
You have to set the the color like this:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    text: {
      secundary: 'black'
     }
   }
  }
});
```

for error the path is `palette.error.main`

the easiest way to find the right variables is to look directly into the [code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/FormLabel/FormLabel.js#L9)